# How can you sniff packets from a switch?

Tags: router, sniffing

For example, if you are using wireshark and you have the NIC set on promiscious mode, will this only allow you to sniff on packets wirelessy from a hub? Because a hub sends data on all ports.

Answer (score 1):

From [this site](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet)

> You generally need to use your switches **monitor mode** which can dedicate a port to connect your (Wireshark) capturing device. It's sometimes called '*port mirroring*' or '*port monitoring*'.

Comment: Can I do this wirelessly? I thought in order  to mirror a port, it first had to have the mirror physical port on the router itself. Is there a way to do this wireless?

Comment: You need different drivers and the technique is different, but yes.  See: https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/blog/how-to-capture-wifi-traffic-using-wireshark-on-windows/